Change Shared Drive icon in Windows 10 with Registry setting
I want to make my desktop look a little more to my liking, and that includes changing some of the icons. One of the icons I want to change is the shared drive icon:

I want to do this using the Registry to make the solution more portable, and know that I can change some icons using the following key:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons

For example:
Name        Type        Data
(Default)   REG SZ      (value not set)
3           REG_SZ      s:\ico\places\folder.ico
4           REG_SZ      S:\ico\status\folder-open.ico

Keys 3 and 4 represent the folder icons, and I’m guessing that there should be a setting for the above icon, but I can’t find any information anywhere on that.
Any ideas what the Registry key for the shared drive icon is?
I’ve been referred to Change drive icon in Windows 10 with a custom *.ico file, which seems to work for the icons in the Explorer, but the Desktop icon doesn’t seem to be affected.
Update
I don’t know why, but after a few reboots, and just a little hand-waving, it works as expected.
The correct key is 9;
Name        Type        Data
(Default)   REG SZ      (value not set)
3           REG_SZ      s:\ico\places\folder.ico
4           REG_SZ      S:\ico\status\folder-open.ico
9           REG_SZ      S:\ico\places\network-server.ico

(Obviously, I’ve copied my icons to a separate folder above).

Does Change drive icon in Windows 10 with a custom *.ico file answer your question?

@DavidPostill Thanks for the link. I’ve just tried that now, but the desktop icon doesn’t seem to change, even after a restart …

@Manngo To save you time when you're testing, instead of rebooting, in Task Manager restart explorer.exe (if using Win <11, you'll need to end all but one instance of explorer.exe, then restart the remaining one) and end the process of Desktop Window Manager, ticking the box to approve doing so.

what do you mean by desktop? the image looks like its in an explorer window and not on the desktop.

@NickSlash The image above was copied from the desktop. If I open an Explorer window and view the desktop folder, the icon is what I have selected. However, the one on the desktop stays the same, even after rebooting.

@JW0914 Thanks, I have a batch file to do that for me. The restart was only because the change didn’t work and someone was bound to as whether I’d restarted.

@Manngo Have you tried specifying the icon in desktop.ini?

How have you added the icon to the desktop? Other than creating a shortcut, I cant think of a way to get it there? There is a Network icon available in Desktop Icon Settings but no option for a specific location.
